# jquery mobile reusing the same header / Programmatically inject component

Tags: jquery-mobile, components

I want to have a complex header and reuse it in every page.
This is my page sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/HBgTp/2/

```html
<div data-inset="true" id="MainScreen" data-theme="a" data-role="page"> 
    <div class="MainHeaderPlaceHolder">
        <!-- PUT HERE THE HEADER -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="MainHeaderWrapper">
    <div data-inset="true" data-role="header">

    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to inject the header like this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".MainHeaderPlaceHolder").append($("#MainHeaderWrapper").html());
   $('.MainHeaderPlaceHolder').trigger('create');
 });
```

Nothing happened, What is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would have thought this would be better done server side, no? Via PHP perhaps?

Comment: @lain_b - Maybe, but how in jeneral I can inject components dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, If you want to go down this route

```
var html = "some html string";//just easier than pulling it from html - to my mind anyway
$(".MainHeaderPlaceHolder").append( html );
```

should work, but that's what you're doing so...

Comment: Well I do see the html inserted, but the styling is not applied. Presumably, this is because JQM runs scripts adding css,etc on the page before your script. I know it's not necessarily the answer to your question but I would definitely go server-side here.